# Spring Data JPA: What is wrong or how to correct this jpql query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The entity relationships are -
A student belongs to one college And a college can have multiple students.
So there is  ManyToOne relationship between Student --> College And a OneToMany relationship between College --> Student.

The entities are as below.

```
@Entity
public class College {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int collegeId;

    private String collegeName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Student.class, mappedBy = "college") 
    private List<Student> students;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int studentId;

    private String studentName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "collegeId_fk")
    private College college;
```

**1) I am using the below jpql query in spring data jpa repository.**

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM College c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.students where c.collegeId IN (2)")
public List<College> findByCollegeIdsJPQL();
```

I am expecting that a list with single college entity to be returned as collegeId is primary key for the College Entity and I am giving only one id for the `IN`.
But What I am getting is a list of colleges all with same primary key (collegeId=2). The size of returned list is equal to the number students in the college.

```
System.err.println("collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL().size(): " + collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL().size()); 
//output: collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL().size(): 6
```

And for

```
collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL().forEach( System.err::println );
```

output:
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]

**2) Another issue i noticed,**
calling `collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL()` for second time is causing another sql query ie DB hit. Can not this be served from session(first level) cache. I have annotated the calling method with

```
  @Transactional
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
```

output log -

```
2022-02-20 15:10:59.140[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [6]
collegeRepo.findByCollegeIdsJPQL().size(): 6
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.153[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByCollegeIdsJPQL]: This method is not transactional.
Hibernate: 
    select
        college0_.college_id as college_1_1_0_,
        students1_.student_id as student_1_12_1_,
        college0_.college_name as college_2_1_0_,
        students1_.college_id_fk as college_3_12_1_,
        students1_.student_name as student_2_12_1_,
        students1_.college_id_fk as college_3_12_0__,
        students1_.student_id as student_1_12_0__ 
    from
        college college0_ 
    left outer join
        student students1_ 
            on college0_.college_id=students1_.college_id_fk 
    where
        college0_.college_id in (
            2
        )
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.245[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(3)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.246[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(3)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.247[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[on(3)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.403[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.404[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.405[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [3]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.405[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.405[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [4]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [5]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_1_1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([student_1_12_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [6]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.406[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m extracted value ([college_3_12_0__] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
College [collegeId=2, collegeName=college2]
[2m2022-02-20 15:10:59.407[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m18416[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completing transaction for [com.demo.MyRunner.run]
```

Comment: In my experience, using `@ManyToOne` is bad  practice, maybe only persisting `collegeId` in `Student.class` and remove field `students` under `College.class`  would be a better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Because `LEFT JOIN` will return the combination of a college and its student. So if a college has N students , N records will be returned. You have to add `DISTINCT` to remove the duplication :

```java
@Query("SELECT distinct c FROM College c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.students where c.collegeId IN (2)")
public List<College> findByCollegeIdsJPQL();
```

However, it will cause the generated SQL has `distinct` keyword which may has performance impact. So since Hibernate 5.2, they provides a query hint called `hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough` which can configure not to add `distinct` keyword in the generated SQL and Hibernate will help to remove the duplication instead :

```java
@Query("SELECT distinct c FROM College c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.students where c.collegeId IN (2)")
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false"))
public List<College> findByCollegeIdsJPQL();
```

For details , please see this [blog post](https://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/).

(2) It is normal. You have to configure 2nd level cache and query cache to prevent another DB hit. 1st level cache mainly works when getting an entity by ID using `EntityManager#get()` in the same transaction. It does not work when using JPQL query.

Comment: right, 1) so i have use the jpql with distinct. ++1. And 2) when i do `collegeRepo.getById(2)` i can see only query is executed as you explained.

Comment: Eclipse suggested these - `javax.persistence.QueryHint` and `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints`;. why one is from jpa and the other from spring

Comment: because spring-data-jpa is built on top of jpa

Comment: what if i change from List to Set = `public Set<College> findByCollegeIdsJPQL();
`, i see the duplicates are not coming, but not sure if this is recommended way? and if there will be performance impact if there are millions of record?.

Comment: could you upvote the Q if you like it as it seems to be very much valid and your answer addresses it. I see this could be quite a normal situation that every spring data jpa user should be aware of.

Comment: sure. It depends on if the generated query will has distinct on it or not . i did not try it and hence don't know

Comment: if you got time - would you mind helping with this [Criteria API and JPQL API with GROUP BY and CONCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129333/criteria-api-and-jpql-api-with-group-by-and-concat/73163002#73163002)